# Algorithm to move mouse from one point to another in a straight line

Tags: java, algorithm, math, formula, equation

I am trying to make a small program that will move the mouse from the current position to the given position. Here is a method that i can use which will move the mouse from one point to another but without animation:

```
moveMouse(int x, int y);
```

This will move the mouse from the current coordinates to x,y on screen without animation. Now my job is to move the mouse to that coordinate, but it should also show the mouse moving one pixel at a time. I need to create a loop which moves the mouse cursor few pixels x and y at a time so that Here is what i have been thinking:

```
public void moveMouseAnimation(x,y){
      //Integers x2 and y2 will be the current position of the mouse cursor
      boolean isRunning = true;
      while(isRunning){
           delay(10); // <- 10 Milliseconds pause so that people can see the animation
           x2 -= 1;
           y2 -= 1;
           moveMouse(x2,y2);
           if(x2 == x && y2 == y) isRunning = false; //Ends loop
      }
}
```

Now i need to find correct x2 and y2 values so that the mouse moves in a straight line and reaches x and y at last. Could someone help me.

Comment: Distance, division, and the desired number of frames shown, are your friend. Once along the x axis, and once along the y axis. (Take into account possible rounding errors when converting floating-point numbers to ints.)

Comment: @TheNail : Nope, just trying to make a simple program to practise my java skills, but couldnt think of a algorithm

stakx : Yes i tried that but did not work properly, thanks anyways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is the code to do that. This code uses Bresenham Line Algo. For more ref on soln try [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) if you are looking not to have jagged lines

```
    boolean steep = Math.abs(y1 - y0) > Math.abs(x1 - x0);
    if (steep) {
        int t;
        // swap(x0, y0);
        t = x0;
        x0 = y0;
        y0 = t;
        // swap(x1, y1);
        t = x1;
        x1 = y1;
        y1 = t;
    }
    if (x0 > x1) {
        int t;
        // swap(x0, x1);
        t = x0;
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = t;

        // swap(y0, y1);
        t = y0;
        y0 = y1;
        y1 = t;
    }
    int deltax = x1 - x0;
    int deltay = Math.abs(y1 - y0);
    int error = deltax / 2;
    int ystep;
    int y = y0;
    if (y0 < y1)
        ystep = 1;
    else
        ystep = -1;

    for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++) {
        if (steep)
            moveMouse(y, x);
        else
            moveMouse(x, y);
        error = error - deltay;
        if (error < 0) {
            y = y + ystep;
            error = error + deltax;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, didnt know about this bresenham's line algorithm

Answer (score 9):

You want the [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm). It is commonly used to draw a line between two points, but you, instead of drawing a line, will move the mouse along it.

[image: Illustration of Bresenham's line algorithm]

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are attempting to solve is that of linear interpolation, in that you have a linear function, that of a line between the starting point (x0, y0) and the ending point (x1, y1).

Luckily the solution is simple. The Wikipedia article gives examples almost exactly what you're trying to do.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Answer (score 2):

You could interpolate a straight line....basically fitting y=mx+b to the given points.